# Why does this ffmpeg line make image_0 gray?

Tags: ffmpeg

Why does this ffmpeg line make image_0 gray?

```
ffmpeg -i image_0.jpg -i image_1.jpg -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=619x800,format=yuvj444p" -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h):flags=bicubic'[0max][1ref];[1ref][0max]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h)':flags=bicubic[1max][0max];[2][0max]overlay=x=132[overl];[overl][1max]vstack" -pix_fmt yuvj444p -frames:v 1 -y combined.png
```

[image_0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b51SJ.jpg) / [image_1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC3Z7.jpg) / [combined.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRT2t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `format=auto` to the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay): otherwise the default value of `yuv420` will be applied and will look ugly.

```
ffmpeg -y -i image_0.jpg -i image_1.jpg -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=619x800,format=yuvj444p" -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h):flags=bicubic'[0max][1ref];[1ref][0max]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h)':flags=bicubic[1max][0max];[2][0max]overlay=x=132:format=auto[overl];[overl][1max]vstack" -frames:v 1 combined.png
```

Make sure your `ffmpeg` is from the current git master branch or at least from the 3.4 release branch or newer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated to ffmpeg-20181005-50a2347-win64-static. format=auto solved the problem. But combined pic still doesn't look exactly like the same conversion in Photoshop. I align them perfectly with original and see some values in difference mode. Mostly it because Photoshop adds some sharpness with its "bicubic automatic". I don't know whether ffmpeg has this option or not? But even the first pic that was not upscaled also has small difference compare to its original. Can I do something with it?

Comment: Combined image exported from Photoshop to png has 0 difference in difference mode.

Comment: @senops I won't have access to Photoshop until Monday. You should ask a new question about that.